# Why NSUserDefaults return 'nil'?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, null

can someone explain me why NSUserDefaults is returning me "nil" for an object that is not? 
I have a view with some settings for a game, there is a textfield in where user can write his name. I save this name in NSUserDefaults and put it as placeholder for the other times user enter this view.
I set the object like that:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *fieldName = _nameField.text;
[defaults setObject:fieldName forKey:@"playerName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And the placeholder:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
_nameField.placeholder = [defaults objectForKey:@"playerName"];
```

And this works perfectly!
But, when a user end a game I want to save his score in a database, if this score is among the top ten; and of course I save the score with the name he wrote in the settings view.
I found (putting some breakpoints) that after this code that runs when user made a record score:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *name = [defaults objectForKey:@"playerName"];
```

The variabile `name` is `"nil"`. 
I don't really know why this happens because the same code in the settings view returns the name and not a "nil".

Comment: Your code looks OK, so there must be something else breaking this.

Comment: Try to check if your `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` method returns `YES`.

Comment: Code looks Ok. Make sure you are running in debug mode (if you will run in release, the name will appear nil eventhou it isn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
[defaults synchronize];
```

istead

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Sorry for repeat - @Gio Bact asks me about it.

Comment: I understand it now - thank you! Let delete our ealrlier comments.