# Alternative to NSUserDefaults to Save Bool?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, nsuserdefaults

Currently I am using `NSUserDefaults` to save and load a bool value like this:

```
-(void)saveSettingOn{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:hapticKey];
}

-(void)saveSettingOff{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:hapticKey];
}

-(void)loadSetting{
    isHapticOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:hapticKey];
}
```

At launch I load the setting in the `AppDelegate` like so:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self loadSetting];
    return YES;
}
```

Sometimes when I launch the app, the `hapticKey` has a value of `nil` or `NO`, even though it should be `YES` (even after a force quit).

I've seen on Stackoverflow that others experience similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695622/why-nsuserdefaults-return-nil) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756036/nsuserdefaults-objectforkey-sometimes-nil).

It's difficult to reproduce because it appears to be random, however it does appear to occur more often when Application hasn't been launched in a while, although that may be coincident.

What alternatives are there for store a `BOOL` value for such a setting?

Comment: User defaults has gotten a little flakey, but mostly because of complications added to make updates to the defaults data atomic and thread safe. I've heard of a few developers having issues when running under the debugger but then those issues disappear when they run the app normally, so check that. Also, if you're constantly killing your app its defaults might become "locked" and the next instance won't be able to read them—try killing the `cfprefsd` agent(s) and/or restarting.

Comment: Finally, if you store values in the instant that your app is quiting, consider sending a `synchronize` message. But this is the only time that's appropriate; calling `synchronize` is not voodoo that you call after every set.

Comment: But overall, this is exactly what `NSUserDefaults` is for and you're using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you changing the data，`NSUserDefaults` sending a synchronize message，but you exit the program and the data isn't saved.

So you need to call `synchronize` manually to save the data.

Comment: Don't use `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize?language=objc) _"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_